# Скачивание pdf файла с помощью библиотеки dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

Такая проблема, требуется создать pdf файл, сохранить его на сервере, отправить по почте и сохранить на пк пользователю. Сохранение на сервере и отправка на почту выполняются отлично, но при сохранении файла на пк пользователя происходит проблема, файл сохраняется, но при этом php страница с контентом закрывается.
Код php страницы:

```
<?php
  echo $my_html;//Отображение страницы,в переменной код страницы 
  header('Content-language:en-GB');
  $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  require_once($root."/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
  use Dompdf\Dompdf;
  $dompdf = new Dompdf(array('enable_remote' => true));
  $dompdf->load_html($my_html);
  $dompdf->setPaper( 'A4', 'portrait' );
  $dompdf->render();//генерация pdf
  $output = $dompdf->output();
  $extension = "pdf";
  $filename = getRandomFileName("/pdf", $extension);
  file_put_contents("pdf/".$filename.".pdf", $output);//сохранение на сервер 

  require($root.'/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->setFrom($_GET['email']);
  $mail->addAddress('cer-c@mail.ru');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
  $mail->msgHTML("От: ".$_GET['name']."\r\n Телефон: ".$_GET['telephone']."\r\n Коммент: ".$_GET['comment']);
  $mail->addAttachment($root."/pdf/".$filename.".pdf");
  $r = $mail->send();//отправка на почту
  $dompdf->stream("file.pdf");//Сохранение на пк пользователю
?>
```

В чём может быть проблема и как её исправить?

Comment: Делайте ссылку, открывающуюся в новой вкладке. Тогда и файл сохраниться и контент не закроется

Comment: @ArchDemon, что то я не понял, можете по подробнее расписать?

Comment: `<a target="_blank" ...` http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/target